# Use a field id without fetching entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, fetch

I have two entities related by a field and I can't get the id of the parent without fecthing the whole parent record.

For example:

```
@Entity
public class Country implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="COD_COUNTRY")
    private String codCountry;

    private String nameCountry;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private UserPK id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="COD_COUNTRY")
    private Country country;
}
```

And then I have this select:

```
SELECT U.ID, U.NAME, U.COD_COUNTRY FROM TB_USERS U WHERE U.ID = 25
```

When I debug the result I can see the field country retrieved ready to be fetched, but I just want the ID that shows in the handler variable:

```
lastUser    User  (id=559)  
    country Country_$$_jvstaaf_f  (id=566)  
        codCountry  null    
        handler JavassistLazyInitializer  (id=578)  
            componentIdType null    
            constructed true    
            entityName  "com.company.project.persistence.entity.Country" (id=583)   
            getIdentifierMethod null    
            id  "ITA" (id=584)
            initialized true    
            interfaces  Class<T>[1]  (id=585)   
            overridesEquals false   
            persistentClass Class<T> (com.company.project.persistence.entity.Country) (id=126)  
            readOnly    false   
            readOnlyBeforeAttachedToSession null    
            replacement null    
            session null    
            sessionFactoryUuid  null    
            setIdentifierMethod null    
            specjLazyLoad   false   
            target  Country  (id=593)   
            unwrap  false   
        nameCountry null    
    userFields  "bla bla" (id=567)
```

How can I get the ID in users without fecthing the whole country record?

Thanks :)

Comment: I am curious about it too. One thing I would try is making the `User.country` field `@ManyToOne(...,optional=false)`, if it makes sense for the business model. This way the provider knows the `country` is never null and, together with `LAZY`, may inject a lazy proxy `Country` object to the `country` field. If the provider is smart enough, it will not load the entire country just by asking the id. Additionally there is the workaround of mapping the `COD_COUNTRY` column to another field that has `insertable=false, updatable=false` - but this is a workaround.

Comment: I guess there isn't an answer to this so I've done as you've said and map the column to another field and use it when needed. Thank you Nikos ;)